# Matlab GUI. Set pushbutton handles in another .m file

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a big Matlab code and now I am trying to connect it to GUI. I have created a function

```
function z = interface_master(handles)
```

which first gets initial parameters from GUI text edit box and then runs a number of .m files using these parameters, for example

```
n = get(handles.n_value,'String');
n = str2num(n);
assign('base','n',n)
run('code_1')
run('code_2')
...
```

Within this 'codes' I create and save a number of figures. I would like now for the User to be able to display a figure of his choice within GUI. Lets say I will have 3 different push buttons (Push1, Push2, Push3) and User after pressing Push1 will get Figure_A displayed. Then after pressing Push2, he will get Figure_B replacing Figure_A, and so on. Can I somehow make it work just setting handles in my function `interface_master`?

I don't want to overcrowd my `interface.m` file and so far I managed to do everything else (reading values, displaying messages) in this additional `interface_master` file, by just connecting both through `interface_master(handles)` in the interface callback functions. But now I am stuck with these push buttons.

I would really appreciate some help here. I have never done any GUI before.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what your code does. Does `n` currently dictate which figure is shown? Is there any chance you can post the relevant parts of `code_1` or `code_2`?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to implement some design pattern (e.g. MVP, MVC) in MATLAB? Much like Suever, I'm confused about what you're trying to do and *why*. Could you maybe provide a diagram/flowchart of the desired behavior...?

Comment: code_1 and code_2 are quite big Matlab scripts calculating many variables for a given number of samples n. Then code_1 and code_2 are saving results and saving figures. They work well without GUI. I try to connect GUI in the way that a User defines himself the number of samples. Then code_1 and code_2 run to calculate all the results. At the end I would like the User to be able to display a figure of his choice within GUI. The figures are already generated and saved (without displaying) by code_1 and code_2. Maybe I overcomplicated things. This is basically what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very much simplified version of what I am doing. In general code_1 and code_2 are much much bigger and the interface will be displaying more messages, while code_1 and code_2 save around 20 different figures. But what I am struggling with can be demonstrated by a simple code calculating polynomials.

```
%% code_1.m 
x = linspace(-1,1) ;
y = x.^n ;


%% code_2.m
f = figure('visible','off');
plot(x,y);
set(f,'Visible','on')
saveas(f,'power_plot_1','fig')
delete(f)
g = figure('visible','off');
plot(x,x.^(n+1));
set(f,'Visible','on')
saveas(g,'power_plot_2','fig')
delete(g)

%%% master.m
function z = master(handles)

n = get(handles.n_value,'String')
n = str2num(n) ;
assignin('base','n',n)

if (n < 1) 
   message = ('small n') ;
elseif (n>10)
    message = ('large n') ;
else
message=('hello world') ;

run('code_1') 
run('code_2')

end
set(handles.text1,'String',message)
```

and here is the interface:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5zoGVwgJhoM/V1qdiyd667I/AAAAAAAACQ0/oaTQHYn13gIuLoSb42Q7N66AV102e-VjQCCo/s912/inter.png